# Problems to use ajaxstart and ajaxstop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried to use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` to showing a loader as long as all functions load.

I consult all the urls and send a request to each of them, So until they do not load all do not hide the loader.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: getBaseUri() + 'dashboard/index',
      method: 'GET',
      success:function(data){

    var datas  = data['return'];
    var urls   = [];
    var idDash = [];
    var types  = [];

    /*
     * I go through the data to send the data of each dashboard
     */
    for (var i in datas) {
        //Urls, dashboard ids and descriptions are saved in an array
        urls.push({
            url: datas[i].route,
            id: datas[i].id,
            title: datas[i].privilege,
            div: datas[i].div
        });
        idDash.push(datas[i].id); 
        types.push(datas[i].type); 

        /*
         * I send the parameters to the receiveData ()
         */

        receiveData(datas[i].route, datas[i].sign, datas[i].class, datas[i].div, datas[i].privilege, datas[i].type, types, idDash, datas[i].id, urls, datas[i].label, datas[i].xaxis, datas[i].yaxis, datas[i].background);
    }
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
});


function receiveData(url, sign, iconClass, div, title, type, types, idDash, id, urls, label, xaxis, yaxis, background) {


    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        var datas = data['return'];
        if (type === "Bar") {
            barChart(datas, title, div, type, types, idDash, id, urls);
        }

        if (type === "Indicator") {
            indicatorsChart({
                data: datas,
                div: div,
                title: title,
                icon: sign,
                class: iconClass,
                idDash: id
            });
        }

        if (type === "Sowing") {
            sowingIndicator({
                data: datas,
                div: div,
                title: title,
                idDash: id
            });
        }

        if (type === "BarChart") {
            barCharts({
                data: datas,
                div: div,
                title: title,
                url: url,
                label: label,
                xaxis: xaxis,
                yaxis: yaxis,
                type: sign,
                background: background
            });
        }
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
}
```

I have used this but it doesn´t work:

```
$(".loader").bind("ajaxStart", function () {
      $(".loader").show();
    }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
      $(".loader").hide();
    });
```

I don´t know if I am doing something wrong, I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks!

Comment: use $( document ).ajaxtStart(...)

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work"? What is the error? What do you see in console? Do the Ajax call work?

Comment: in console doesn´t show anything, when I use ajaxstart it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not binding to the correct element - you typically should bind `ajaxStart` to the document itself:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function () {
      $(".loader").show();
    }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {
      $(".loader").hide();
    });
```

And a JSFiddle demonstrating this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/x196bb4L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$( document).ajaxStart(function () {
      $(".loader").show();
    });
$( document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(".loader").hide();
});
```

[**Ref**](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: It doesn´t work, I had tried with this but it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

You could show the loader at the time you trigger the ajax call, and hide it on ajax callback like this:

```
var loader = $('.loader');
loader.show();
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
     loader.hide();
  },
  error: function() {
     loader.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: It can work, but only show the loader one time, I need to show it until all functions load